# Prove the limit of a sequence when n is a negative exponent

Tags: real-analysis

Prove, directly from the ε − N definition, that 0 is not the limit of the sequence $$s_n = 1+ \frac{1}{2^n}$$

The actual limit is 1. So, I'm trying to prove that 0 is not the limit. However, when trying the computation, I'm not sure how to transform 
$$1+ \frac{1}{2^n} <ε$$ into something where $$n>ε$$ So far I put a natural log on both sides, but it looks very messy.  Any thoughts?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You take the negation of "$\lim a_n =0$" in the wrong way.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose it is! That means that for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can always find a positive integer $N$ so that $|1+2^{-n}-0| < \epsilon $ for all $n \geq N$. Making $\epsilon = 1$ we have

$$ 1 + \frac{1}{2^n} < 1 $$

which implies that $\frac{1}{2^n} < 0$. False.